# RoR Tutorial question - where are my files?

Tags: controls, github, version, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm on Chapter 9 of RoR Tutorial by Mr. Hartl.  However, it seems like the last 4 chapters worth of coding is gone.  I've been following his git version control instructions during every lesson.  But when I last checked my github account, every file showing in the master branch is from, at latest, 4 chapters ago.  Was I not properly checking out?  I'm so frustrated right now.  Please help.  Thank you very much.

P.S. I realize this started to happen when I typed the following (rake db:reset).  But then again, I would think this would only affect the database entries, not my whole damn project.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Does the code exist on your local system? If it does, did you push your code to GitHub?

```
git push [remote-name] [branch]
```

If you've used the default names it should be

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: I haven't done a 'git push' in 4 chapters.  Instead, for the past 4 chapters, I would end with 'git add .' and 'git commit -am "blah" and 'git checkout master'  I simply followed his instructions. :(  Maybe because I haven't done a 'push' in awhile?  My code no longer exists on my local system--or not where I can find them in the root directory.

Comment: Does 'git log' return anything of your commit history or just "Not a git repository"?

Comment: It returns all the changes I made prior to Chapter 5--the same as my GitHub account.  Btw, I really appreciate you trying to help me.  I assume I'll have to re-do everything.  I'm just afraid of repeating this occurrence.

Comment: After checking my hidden .git folder (and subsequently, the 'log' folder), I opened a file named HEAD, which shows all the latest changes I made throughout chapters 5 to 9.  But i don't see any of the files necessary to revert back to the latest update.

Comment: Hmm, my guess is you did a checkout *before* you committed your changes. I recommend you walk through your commit history and see if there is any code to be saved. Maybe you've checked out an earlier commit, and committed that code. If that doesn't work out (and didn't make a backup in the meantime, I'm afraid your code is lost. 

Mr. Hartl did however upload the application's code to GitHub (https://github.com/mhartl/first_app), so you could grab parts of the code from there. Sadly, it doesn't include tags or commit history...

Comment: Thank you Xoc!  Actually, he did here: https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app/commits/master/  I didn't think about looking at his github account.  I'll just copy his code down.  I hope you have a wonderful New Year! :)

Comment: Great! Have fun learning Rails and a good New Year to you, too.